# implement "&" to column pointer get unknown result

Tags: c, pointers

the column pointer p1 is defined as below

```
int a[3][4]={{1,3,5,7},
            {9,11,13,15},
            {17,19,21,23}};
int *p1= &a[0][0];
```

Then,`p[i]` represent the i'th element in the array, e.g., `p1[4]=9`

And I know the row pointer `p2`

```
int (*p2)[4] = a;
```

I can  use `p2[i][j]` to get the `a[i][j]`.

But, why can't I get the correct result by using `(&p1)[i][j]`? I think `(&p1)` is equal to `p2`, but in fact I can't understand the result.

I try to print the value of `(&p1)[0][0]),(&p1)[0][2]),(&p1)[1][0]),(&p1)[1][2])`, part of them are correct. It's weird.

[image: Output Screen-grab]

Comment: Sorry,I made a mistake.It should be **int (*p2)[4] = a;**.

Comment: p1 is a pointer variable. &p1 is the address of that variable. &p1 has nothing to do with the value of the contents of p1. &p1 also has no relationship to the address of `a` except possibly by implementation detail accident. &p1 isn't properly usable to access `a`. &p1 also has no relationship to p2. Don't know why you think so. You are confusing yourself.

Comment: Please do not use bold to highlight code. Rather use backticks to format code in a fixed-width font.

Comment: But why isn't the size of `(&p1)` is 8 byte?See in the picture.https://photos.app.goo.gl/s3KdGG6zXASRLt9h9

Comment: The size of `&p1` is whatever the size of a pointer is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Where in that screenshot do you print `sizeof(&p1)`?

Comment: As @AviBerger said, `&p1` is not the array. Since `p1` points to the array, you would have to use `*(&p1)` to access the array, which is basically the same as just `p1`.

Comment: @Barmar Of course `sizeof(&p1)`is 8 byte.I mean,the address of (&p1)[1] isn't increasing by 8 byte.That's what I'm confused.In one progress`p1` is 0x62FDE0,but `(&p1)[1]`is 0x8815C0.

Comment: Fwiw, `int *p1 = &a[0][0];` is superfluous anyway. `int *p1 = a[0];` is sufficient to load the proper base address. Regardless, half of your uses of `&p1` ultimately invoke UB. The ones that don't are `(&p1)[0][0]` and `(&p1)[0][0]`, and those only pass because they're synonymous with `p1[0]` and `p1[2]` respectively. Given a pointer variable `p`, the expression `(&p)[0]` is synonymous with `*(&p)`, which is synonymous with simply `p`.

Answer (score 2):

(&p1)[0] would give you p1. Therefore (&p1)[0][0] and (&p1)[0][2] would give you the correct result.

but (&p1)[1] would give the pointer written after the pointer to p1. Which is garbage. so (&p1)[1][X] would be garbage

it's like you'd write:

```
int **p1_ptr = &p1
```

and then use:

```
p1_ptr[0][X] --> p1[X]
p1_ptr[1][X] --> (*(p1_ptr++))[X]
```

Answer (score 0):

`(&p1)[i][j]` takes the address of the pointer so that's wrong. You want to dereference the pointer.

The most correct pointer type to use in this case would be `int (*p)[3][4]`. However, that comes with the disadvantage of having to type `(*p)[i][j]` each time we de-reference. To get rid of that, we could use a pointer to the first row (the first item in the array), instead of a pointer to the whole array. And that's what you are doing already with `int (*p2)[4]`, so you can use the far more convenient `p[i][j]` access.

> I think (&p1) is equal to p2

No, we cannot use the address-of operator to go "up" one level in the type system. Each time we dereference something, or each time an array decays into a pointer to its first item, type information is "lost". As in, the resulting type has no clue about belonging to a larger array. So an `int*` could for example either point at an item in an array, or at a single item. Nothing in the `int*` declaration itself tells you what it points at beyond one particular `int` item.